# Excel DAO code used to change Access query based on userform does not close Access properly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, userform, dao

I have an access database which holds daily performance reports and have created a query which filters that data by three separate categories and a date range so that users can manipulate the data to see data relevant to their job roles.

I have created an Excel document which has a table linked to the access query and some user forms so that users can select the options relevant to them for the three categories and date range. I run the code below when opening the workbook and also have a button which allows the user to change the query if they desire. The code on workbook open performs perfectly, the query is updated to the relevant options and then excel tables are refreshed.

If I then try to rerun the query I get a runtime error 3045 "database file already in use" error on the

```
Set dbs = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Me\Database1.accdb", True)
```

line. If I try and open the database directly after having run the code once and whilst Excel is still open then I can only open it in read-only mode. I therefore assume that I am not closing the database properly however looking on google seems to say that closing and then setting the variables = nothing it should be closed properly.

Thanks in advance for any assistance. Here is the code:

```
Public category1 As Variant
Public category2 As Variant
Public category3 As Variant
Public startdate As Variant
Public enddate As Variant

Public Sub Edit_access_Query()
Dim ws As DAO.workspace
Dim dbs As DAO.database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim sSQL As String
Dim errorcount As Integer

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

'Show user a user form with checkbox options to filter data by three different categories
CategoryUserFrm.Show
If category1 = Empty Or category2 = Empty Or category3 = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Query change cancelled. Table will not update."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Show user a user form with textboxes to select a start date for the data range
StartUserFrm.Show
If startdate = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Query change cancelled. Table will not update."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Show user a user form with textboxes to select a start date for the data range
EndUserFrm.Show
If enddate = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Query change cancelled. Table will not update."
    Exit Sub
End If

'create string which will be used in the access query. only dyanmic bits are after where - category filtering and date range
sSQL = "SELECT x, y ,z FROM a " _
& "LEFT JOIN a ON b = c WHERE (" _
& "(([a].[Date]) >= #" & startdate & "# And ([a].Date) <= #" & enddate & "#) " _
& category1 & category2 & categroy3 & ");"

Set ws = DAO.CreateWorkspace("NewWorkspace", "admin", "")
Set dbs = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Me\Database1.accdb", True)
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("User Lookup")

qdf.Sql = sSQL

qdf.Close
dbs.Close
ws.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

'next three lines refresh the tables in excel which are reading off the access query. doevents to create a bit of time buffer in case of poor connection
DoEvents
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents
category1 = Empty
category2 = Empty
category3 = Empty
startdate = Empty
enddate = Empty
Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
errorcount = errorcount + 1
If errorcount < 5 Then
Resume
ElseIf MsgBox("Connection problem. Click Okay to retry or cancel to exit.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    category1 = Empty
    category2 = Empty
    category3 = Empty
    startdate = Empty
    enddate = Empty
    Exit Sub
Else
Call Edit_access_Query
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that if your tables are linked to the database, the connection is locking the db when the tables are refreshed, not your code. If you open the workbook without running the code, refresh the tables manually and then try and open the accdb file, do you still get the read-only effect?

Comment: Hi Rory. Thanks so much for the quick reply - it appears as if you correct. If I open the excel file and exit out of the query and then open access it opens as normal. If I then close access and refresh the tables (Data tab -> connection section -> refresh all) and then open access I get the read only effect. Do you know if there is a way to change this happening or it is inherent of how tables connected to databases work?

Comment: Check the properties of the connection in Excel (Data-Connections) and make sure the Mode part is set to something like Read, rather than Share Deny Write for example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rory. I changed the mode to read from share deny write and am now getting run time error 3705 "You attempted to open a database that is already opened by...". I will google it myself and hopefully work it out but if you have any other suggests then that'd be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you close Excel and Access and restart to ensure any existing locks were cleared? If so, perhaps try **Share Deny None** as the Mode setting.

Comment: I had closed Excel and Access and reopened (not restarted PC if that is what you mean). Also tried share deny none but seeing the same error 3705 "You attempted to open a database that is already opened by...".

Comment: Do you have more than one connection to that database in the workbook?

Comment: Thanks for your help Rory, I have now resolved the issue. I managed to get it working by setting Mode=ReadWrite and Database Locking Mode=1 within the connection properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from Rory I have managed to resolve this.

For anyone looking at this in the future with similar issues, this is what I did to resolve:

I went into the database connection settings and altered the connection string to set Mode=ReadWrite and Database Locking Mode=1.

The above was what fixed the issue however I made more trouble for myself by altering the data source within the connection string rather than the connection file which meant that some key fields were missed (changing the string to a network rather than local folder meant password parameters were needed).